# How do I redirect a virtual directory to HTTPS?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, routes, windows-server-2012-r2

I have some applications in different virtual directories in IIS 8.5 with the following path:

http://sub.domain.com/logicalgroup/applicationname

How can I redirect requests to HTTPS? I got everything working if it would be without the virt. dir., but with 1 extra folder I can't make it work.

Thanks!